# R read.table skip not working. Why?

Tags: r, read.table

I have a file similar to

```
ColA ColB ColC
A     1    0.1
B     2    0.2
```

But with many more columns.
I want to read the table and set the correct type of data for each column. 
I am doing the following:

```
data <- read.table("file.dat", header = FALSE, na.string = "", 
dec = ".",skip = 1,
colClasses = c("character", "integer","numeric"))
```

But I get the following error:

> Error in scan(...): scan() expected 'an integer', got 'ColB'

What am I doing wrong? Why is it trying to parse also the first line according to colClasses, despite `skip=1`?

Thanks for your help.

**Some notes**: This file has been generated in a Linux environment and is being worked on in a Windows environment. I am thinking of a problem with newline characters, but I have no idea what to do. 
Also, if I read the table without `colClasses` the table is read correctly (skipping the first line) but all columns are `factor` type. I can probably change the class later, but still I would like to understand what is happening.

Comment: Works for me on the example data, although you lose the column names

Answer (score 0):

Instead of skipping first line, you can change header = TRUE and it should work fine.

```
 data <- read.table("file.dat", header = TRUE, na.string = "", 
 dec = ".",colClasses = c("character", "integer","numeric"), sep = ",")
```

Comment: What is the separator in your file? Use the separator parameter and check. I have updated the answer for "," sep.